# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client ASYNC AWAIT not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, ejs

I am trying to verify if some data is in the session. If not the controller will redirect you to another route, to get that data.
The problem is that I am getting an error "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

I search over StackOverflow and I find that everyone that had this problem fix it using it async/await, but i was already using async await.

Your help will be trully appreciated!
Thank you very much!
Jose

```
dashboardCtrl.init = async (req, res) => {
//
  var frontdata = req.session;
  if (!frontdata.user) {
    frontdata.user = await userfacebook.findOne({ where: { 'email': frontdata.passport.user } });

  };
  if (!frontdata.store) {
    tmpstoredata = await userstore.findOne({ where: { 'userfacebookId': frontdata.user.id } });
    if (!tmpstoredata) {
      res.redirect('/toURL');
    };
  };
};
```

Note: I am using EJS MATE.
If i do this

```
dashboardCtrl.init = async (req, res) => {
//
      res.redirect('/toURL');
};
```

Redirect works, the problem is using await. So i dont know how to continue

Comment: do you still get the error if you remove this line: `console.log(tmpstoredata);`

Comment: yes i do have the error.

Answer (score 1):

That error says that you have already sent an answer to the cliente. In other words, you are trying to declare for the second time -> **res.*****.

Check the flow again in case you have twice declared any action on express's "res".

The solution below allows you to have a good structured and readable asynchronous code.

```
dashboardCtrl.init = (req, res) => {

// I think destructuring looks good
let { user, store } = req.session;

(async () => {
    try {
        if (!user) user = await userfacebook.findOne({ where: { 'email': frontdata.passport.user } });
        let tmpstoredata;
        if (!store) tmpstoredata = await userstore.findOne({ where: { 'userfacebookId': frontdata.user.id } });

        if (!tmpstoredata) res.redirect('/toURL');

    } catch (err) {
        // don't forget ;)
    }
})()
};
```

Hope this can help you. 
Greetings.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help.

I am still having the same error. Truly i dont know how to continue

Comment: I would suggest you to go to rest, sleep 8 hours or more and then comeback to the problem with fresh eyes ;) Follow suggestions here. That problem is clear, like stated in this answer you are sending something in the response already at the time you try to send your output, look where are you writing in the response.

Comment: @davidmpaz i understand the answer but it doesnt work, is the same but restructured.
"in this answer you are sending something in the response already at the time you try to send your output" yes, i know. 
but why method 1 doesnt work, when method 2 works.
i have been moving the lines, and it stopped working when I use res.redirect after a DB query

Comment: Try to reproduce your problem here https://stackblitz.com/ that way you can get better help from people in debugging your issue. Only that block of code will not help.

Comment: I am using EJS MATE , as i can see, the problem became there, but dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

- The code was OK
- The problem was the EJS MATE
- I replace it with EJS